# NetSuite saved search formula to find the difference of two custom columns

Tags: sql, plsql, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to make a saved search to find out which assemblies can be built by determining if all the components are in stock. So I currently have this in one column 
CASE WHEN {memberitem.quantityavailable} > 1 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END 
in conjuntion with a sum summary type. I also have a column with "Member Item" selected and a count summary type. How do I make a third column that calculates the difference between these two? (What would I use for the column names essentially) Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
SUM( [first column] ) - COUNT( [second column] )
```

and set the Summary Type to MIN (with this approach the actual aggregation is taking place within your formula, but you still have to select a summary type for the result to display.)

You haven't provided a formula for the second column, so I can only guess what the actual formula you will need is.  If you have just selected a field you would have to convert that to a formula for the purpose of this column.  The end result would be something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN {memberitem.quantityavailable} > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - COUNT({memberitem})
```