# NetSuite saved search formula to determine if all the components are in stock

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Sorry a novice at Stack Overflow, so hope I'm doing this correctly.

I'm trying to make a saved search to find out which assemblies can be built by determining if all the components are in stock. I found a similar question by Garrett Penfield at [NetSuite saved search formula to find the difference of two custom columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60422075/13629861) and was hoping that Garrett or others may be able to assist.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the **Buildable Quantity** of all **Assembly/Bill Of Materials** items:

Create a Item Saved Search as follows:

- **Criteria (Standard) Tab**

  - **Type** ANY OF **Assembly/Bill Of Materials**
  - **Inventory Location** ANY OF **- None -** and **<Your Location>**
  - **Member Item Fields > Inventory Location** ANY OF **- None -** and **<Your Location>**
  - **Member Item Fields > Type** ANY OF **Assembly/Bill Of Materials** and **Inventory Item**

[image: Criteria tab selections]

- **Criteria (Summary) Tab**

  - Type: Minimum
  - Field: Formula (Numeric)
  - Formula: `GREATEST(FLOOR(NVL({memberitem.locationquantityonhand},0)/{memberquantity}),0)`
  - Greater than 0

[image: Criteria tab (summary selections)]

- **Results Tab**

  - **Internal ID** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Name** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Description** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Formula (Numeric)** (Summary type **Minimum**): `GREATEST(FLOOR(NVL({memberitem.locationquantityonhand},0)/{memberquantity}),0)`

[image: Results tab selections]

**Example of results:**
[image: Example of results]

**Notes**

- You may want to change **locationquantityonhand** to **locationquantityavailable** in the formulas used in both the *Criteria (Summary)* and *Results* tabs.

  - Doing so will change the result to only show how many assemblies can be built without using items that are already committed to other customer orders.

Comment: Hi Kane, what a legend thanks a ton for all your help on this.

Comment: No problem! If your Assembly contains non-inventory items you will want to make a small change to ensure that they don't "zero out" the buildable quantity (because they aren't in stock.) Let me know if you need help to fix that. (Hint, just add into the Filter Criteria: Member Item > Type ANY OF Assembly/Bill of Materials, Inventory Item)

Comment: Thanks Kane, are you using NetSuite yourself for business, or are you a NetSuite developer. Our issue revolved around identified and building assembly items that were on back order, and producing a list of these that could be build if all components were in stock. I have commissioned a scrip to be written to facilitate this as it seemed to complicated for a saved search. What do you think? Cheers

Comment: Stephen, I use NetSuite at my workplace, but I am also our in house IT manager/Developer. I have built many NetSuite customizations for within my workplace, some of the larger ones being a native Australia Post integration (no middleware) and our own native Magento connector (no middleware.) What you've described may be possible with a saved search alone. If you haven't already had a script written, or if you aren't satisfied with it, perhaps we could get in contact and work out an approach that will benefit your business.

Comment: Stephen, please accept my answer on this question, then ask a NEW question specifically asking for a way to create a saved search to find the buildable quantity of assembly items that are back-ordered. I have figured it out and will post the answer on the new question!

Comment: Hi Kane, wow sounds like you have has tons of experience with some interesting and complex NetSuite customisations. I very much appreciate your help on answering this question. I will as suggested ask another question.  I am a first time novice on stack so not sure what if anything  I need to do to finish this question off. I thought I had last time, but couldn't give you my 10 out of 10, as I didn't have any cred.. We recently implemented NetSuite, BigCommerce and HubSpot to our Business BrandNet based in Canberra Australia, doing some exciting things :<)

Comment: @StephenDavie Definitely up there with the experience :) You should be able to mark this question as answered by clicking the Tick symbol on the left of my answer. Also, I posted an answer on your other question!

Comment: thanks Kane, I have just seen your latest will go and try this one now. Appreciate the help.